# Getting error from copying row from table to another table

Tags: python, mysql, database, pymysql

I am writing a piece of python code to copy one table from one mysql db to to another mysql db.

I came across some problems like first it was reading null, empty values as 'None' which I had to convert to 'NULL'.

Now it showing following error -

```
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1630, u"FUNCTION datetime.datetime does not exist. 
Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual")
```

When I print the row I can see the entry of datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 25, 8, 24, 51). 
I tried solve this problem by replacing datetime.datetime by datetime.time (http://pymotw.com/2/datetime/) But that also failed.

My code is as follows :

```
import re
from db import conn_main ### database from where to copy
from db import conn ### database where to copy
import datetime

curr1 = conn_main.cursor()
curr2 = conn.cursor()

query = 'SELECT * FROM mytable limit 10'
curr1.execute(query)
for row in curr1:
    if row[0] is None or not row[0]:
            print "error: empty row",row[0]
            continue
    else:
            print "ROW - %s\n" % str(row)
            row = re.sub('None','NULL',str(row))
            query = 'replace into mytable values ' + str(row)
            curr2.execute(query)

curr2.commit()
curr1.close()
curr2.close()
```

Traceback & output row:

```
ROW - (1, '501733938','xyz.emails@gmail.com', None, 'https://www.facebook.com/xyz',
 None, None, None, None, None, '2014-08-10T06:06:33+0000', None, 'xyz', None,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 25, 8, 24, 51), None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 
 None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MY_PYTHON_CODE_FILE_PATH", line 390, in <module> curr2.execute(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 132, in execute result = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 271, in _query conn.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 726, in query self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 861, in _read_query_result result.read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1064, in read first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 826, in _read_packet packet.check_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 370, in check_error raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 116, in raise_mysql_exception _check_mysql_exception(errinfo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 112, in _check_mysql_exception raise InternalError(errno, errorvalue)
```

Can someone help remove this error ... or suggest any other better way to copy table from one database to another in python.

Comment: Will you please provide full traceback?

Comment: `if row[0] is None` isn't enough ? What does `or not row[0]` stands for ? Also did you try `if row[0] == None` ?

Comment: @Lafada added traceback

Comment: @sammy error or problem is not what you mentioned above. I can remove that part :)

Comment: Please provide output of `print "ROW - %s\n" % str(row)`

Comment: @user2952821 There isn't any harm in giving us more information. You don't have to wait for us to ask what something is before you can tell us.

Comment: @Lafada Added row output ... hmmm from next time will add all output at once.

Comment: @Veedrac added output row.

Comment: You're using `re.sub` to replicate `str.replace`. But then I see that you're doing *string replacement* to change `None` → `NULL` and I get *very* suspicious. I'm pretty sure this is not how you're meant to be executing statements.

Comment: @Veedrac I was getting error before adding the replace line that None is undefined column ... So checked the document which states that if want to enter null and empty values we should write NULL so replaced None with NULL. I have no idea why row is printing null values as None.

Comment: You should look into prepared statements.

Comment: I don't know much about SQL, but does `curr2.execute('replace into mytable values (%s)', row)` work?

Answer (score 2):

According to mysql manual up to v 5.7 there is neither function DATETIME (even if there is a datetime TYPE) nor package support (datetime.***). I assume it's the python str that generates datetime.datetime from the binary representation of the datetime in your source database

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: you're trying to use python string representation of some_object as SQL. That's wrong. 
`str(datetime)` will look like 
`datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, milliseconds)`

it's not valid sql string.
If you know what this column number is, you can replace it with string value, like this:

```
row[dt_index] = row[dt_index].isoformat()
```

or with concrete format your database accepts, e.g:

```
row[dt_index] = row[dt_index].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

But I suggest use some libraries or parameterised queries.
Building SQL such a way is very bad and **unsafe** solution.